# Should I use unique ids or the whole sentences when localizing software?

Tags: localization, translation

I need to translate a website to a couple languages, and I've already read how to do it:

1. Mark strings for translation
2. Generate messages file
3. Translate messages file

The problem is, if I use whole sentences as the message ids, in english, for example, then if later I decide to modify the text, I'll have to change it in the code and on each message file . Or I could just change the english translation, but then my english message file will look weird, with translations from english to english which do not match.
Example:

- Original: "I don't know what to do."
- Translation: "I'm not sure what to do."

An alternative is to use unique message ids such as:

- Original: "INDECISION_MESSAGE"
- Translation: "I'm not sure what to do."

The advantage is that I can change translations without changing the id and things will still be consistent. But then there is no easy way for a translator to know what the message should be like as there is no context except by looking at the code.

What would you use?

Comment: Why would you have translations from English -> English? Generally, you have a key/value table for each language. The keys would be consistent across tables.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP people normally use the first approach you mentioned. In ASP.NET the second.
I think it's more of a personal taste and a matter of the framework that you use.

Personally I prefer the second option. Since you normally already have the ID/translation pair somewhere in a list, the translator can just take that list to translate.

What framework do you use?

Comment: Django. I've been thinking about the disadvantages of the second option, and one I'd like to know how you handle is the time lost to think about the IDs, and whether the code isn't harder to read with IDs instead of text in it...

Comment: I think that is personal. You have clearer code without all the text. But you also have less context.